# Why in MediaWiki it is common to wrap templates with the <noninclude> tag?

Tags: mediawiki

In MediaWiki Wikipedia-like websites I often see some `<noninclude>` tag wrapping of templates.

Is it really common to wrap templates with the `<noninclude>` tag and if so, what is the general advantage in doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical structure of a template is

```
template content
<noinclude>
template documentation
</noinclude>
```

which prevents the documentation from showing up everywhere the template is included.